# The word "cooker"

Tags: word-usage, american-english, dictionaries, north-american-english

According to Merriam-Webster, one of the definitions of the word "cooker" is "a person who tends a cooking process (a cook)." The dictionary provides the following example sentence:

> Dad was the traditional COOKER of the big Sunday breakfast.

Native speakers, could you please confirm (or refute) this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would never use *cooker* to refer to a person.  A *cooker* is a device- i.e., a pressure cooker.

Comment: A person employed to operate cooking apparatuses in the commercial preparation of food and drink.

Comment: It's more common to refer to a person as _a cook_.

Comment: From searching for phrases where it's used of a person ("He was the cooker", "she was a cooker" etc.) suggests it's used, but very rarely, and most of those aren't for food (crystal meth or account books instead) or aren't written by native writers.

Comment: In BrEng someone who cooks is called a cook. BUT your sentence doesn't jar as much as you might think -I wouldn't bat an eye if someone said it to me. I think it's because it's clear that Dad is not the usual cook, but on Sunday morning he's The Man and steps in to do the breakfast. There's a bit more action around 'cooker' (for that particular moment) than for someone whose ongoing status is 'cook'.

Comment: Hearing an “er” noun (referring to a person) made from the stem of a verb that is always transitive is probably what sounds funny, but as long as there is an “of [whatever]” prepositional phrase immediately following it to answer the “what/of what” question (as in your example) then I think it sounds fine and even colorful.

Comment: 'Dad was the traditional cooker of the big Sunday breakfast' is not ungrammatical, but 'It was a time-honoured tradition that dad cooked the big Sunday breakfast' sounds less quirky. Agent nouns often sound outlandish ('He was a good putter, but a poor chipper'; 'The waiters in the corridor are getting rather annoyed; they've been waiting for two hours').

Answer (score 2):

Though [cooker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cooker) also means:

> - A person employed to operate cooking apparatuses in the commercial preparation of food and drink.

In more common terms, 
**[Cook and Cooker](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-cook-and-vs-cooker/)**:

> - are two words in the English language that are quite often confused. The word ‘cook’ refers to a person who cooks food or prepares food. On the other hand a cooker is a kind of appliance or an apparatus used in the process of cooking.
> - As a matter of fact the word ‘cooker’ is vividly used in British English rather than American English. The equivalent for cooker in American English is either a range or a stove. The range is otherwise called as cooking range.
> - To say ‘My friend is a very good cooker’ is grammatically wrong. The right way of saying that is ‘My friend is a very good cook.’
> - Since the word ‘cooker’ is used to refer to the apparatus used in the act of cooking, you can use the word in sentences as follows:
>
>   - 1. I prefer to buy gas cooker.
>   - 2. A cooker is not a very expensive apparatus.
> - It is interesting to note that the word ‘cook’ has the same form when it used as a verb and as a noun. When used as a verb the word ‘cook’ means ‘prepare food by beating it’. Observe the sentences:
>
>   - 1. He cooks well.
>   - 2. The food is not cooked well.
> - In both the sentences given above, the word ‘cook’ is used in the sense of ‘preparation of food’. In the second sentence it means ‘the food is not prepared well’.
> - Cooker on the other hand is a container or device meant for cooking food. It is an appliance that is powered by electricity or gas for preparing food.
> - It is interesting to note that in British English the word ‘cooker’ sometimes refers to a fruit, especially an apple that is easily cooked than eaten raw. You cannot relish it eating raw but would enjoy it when cooked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure to *cook* is to prepare food by *heating* it, not *beating* it though.

Comment: While I generally agree with that excerpt, it's not what I would call a reliable source. It is badly written and repetitive, and there's nothing _grammatically_ wrong with "My friend is a very good cooker". It is just what some random person has put on a website, and is of no more value than an unreferenced answer here.

Comment: So, Colin, you're saying that "My friend is a very good cooker" is perfectly acceptable?

Comment: I believe that "cooker" was created the same way as "maker" and "killer". It's a verb, and you add "-er" to refer to the subject who does it. However, Oxford Dictionary does not acknowledge that kind of definition. I also believe you should avoid using "cooker" and just use "cook" or "chef" instead. They're shorter both in letter count and syllables, double win!

Answer (score -1):

I'd much rather say 'traditionally, dad is the one who used to cook the big breakfast on Sunday' - more verbose but still feels right (to me at least)

To refer to a person as a 'cooker' sounds insane - maybe to my old-fashioned mind perhaps? :) Unless metaphorically the intention is to refer to the dad as an appliance..

Comment: Hi sandeep, welcome to EL&U. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: it's not a discussion forum. An answer here is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - as distinct from mere personal opinion. For further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)